# Sorting nested elements based on various columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this is possible. I can't seem to even get started but I have the following HTML. Is it possible to click on a title (Column 1, Column 2 or Column 3) and have everything in the bodyModule get sorted?

```
<div class="moduleRowTitle">
    <div class="column1">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column2">Column 2</div>
    <div class="column3">Column 3</div>
</div>
<div class="bodyModule">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column1">AAAAA</div>
        <div class="column2">BBBBB</div>
        <div class="column3">CCCCC</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column1">BBBBB</div>
        <div class="column2">AAAAA</div>
        <div class="column3">CCCCC</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column1">BBBBB</div>
        <div class="column2">CCCCC</div>
        <div class="column3">AAAAA</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on column2 should sort as the following:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column1">BBBBB</div>
        <div class="column2">AAAAA</div>
        <div class="column3">CCCCC</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column1">AAAAA</div>
        <div class="column2">BBBBB</div>
        <div class="column3">CCCCC</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column1">BBBBB</div>
        <div class="column2">CCCCC</div>
        <div class="column3">AAAAA</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why don't you try it in tables?

Answer (score 0):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/jJ83a/4/)

**Jquery**

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
$('.moduleRowTitle div').click(function(){
     var vals = [];
    var className=$(this).attr('class');
    $( ".bodyModule ."+className).each(function(){
            vals.push($(this).html());
    });
          vals.sort();
    var i=0;
     $( ".bodyModule ."+className).each(function(){
            $(this).html(vals[i]);
            i=i+1;
    });
});
});
```

I hope this is what you expect